# Gallery grid of different size images

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to replicate this design:

[image: example]

The size of the three images is the same and I am using Twitter Bootstrap, but cannot get them to align this way. The idea is to have the bigger image as 6 columns and then the other two would be 6, but on top of each other, aligning to the same height as the bigger one. Any ideas how I can tackle this or any libraries I can use?

**EDIT: add current code**

```
<div class="home-banner-option-three">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding banner-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Banner image" />
            <div class="banner-text">
              <h4 class="banner-title">text</h4>
              <p class="banner-paragraph">text</p>
              <a href="" class="btn banner-btn">text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 noppading banner-right">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                <div class="banner-xs-one">
                  <p>text</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                <div class="banner-xs-two">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Banner image" />
                  <div class="banner-text">
                    <h4 class="banner-title">text</h4>
                    <p class="banner-paragraph">text</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn banner-btn">text</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
                <div class="banner-sm">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Banner image" />
                  <div class="banner-text">
                    <h4 class="banner-title">text</h4>
                    <p class="banner-paragraph">text</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn banner-btn">text</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have removed all the unnecessary source paths and text to keep it readable

Comment: Can you share you code, which you have tried ?

Comment: If these image have same size, use 2 columns `col-8` and `col-4`, so the right images will have height = 1/2 the left. Add class `img-responsive` too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It doesn't use twitter bootstrap or a grid system, its just a couple of simple floats.

```css
.large {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.small {
    float: left;
}
.small img {
    height: 95px;
    display: block;
}
.small img:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="large" />
    <div class="small">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `min-height` to right blocks to match the height of left block. eg.
html code.

```
<div class='col-md-8 block-left'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-12 block-right-top'></div>
      <div class='col-md-12 block-right-bottom'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.block-left{
        height:210px;
    }
    .block-right-top{
        min-height:100px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .block-right-bottom{
        min-height:100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Try to put it in 2 different

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 Height1"> <!--- Left Box---->
      <img src="..."/>
     </div>
      
     <div class="col-md-4"> <!--- Right Box---->
      <div class="col-md-12 Height2">
          <img src="..."/>
      </div>
       
      <div class="col-md-12 Height2">
          <img src="..."/>
      </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Specify the height for col-md-8 - (Height1 class)
Height1 has to be divided by 2 for Height2 class.

Use float is necessary. 
*NB: Not adding any custom CSS. So, plz do not check the output in "Run Code"